# Special characters in my javascript variables keep showing up as �, how do i prevent this?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javascript script which is calling a php page to supply an ajax form with suggestions. The suggestions are returned fine by the php page, but for some reason, when i set the responsetext of the javascript object request as an element in my HTML page, all the special characters (ie. á or ã) show up as this question mark. Is there a function II must run on the response text of the request to make sure these are read properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not serving your HTML pages as UTF-8, the browser will guess an encoding, typically a single-byte Windows codepage depending on the user's locale.

But this doesn't happen for AJAX. With `XMLHttpRequest`, unless you specifically state an encoding in the `Content-Type: ...; charset=` parameter, the browser will treat it as UTF-8. That means if you are actually serving Windows code page 1252 (Western European) content, you will get an invalid UTF-8 sequence and consequent question mark.

You don't want to be using a non-UTF-8 encoding! Make sure you are using UTF-8 throughout your application. Serve all your pages with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, store your data in UTF-8 tables, use `mysql_set_charset()` to choose UTF-8, etc.

In any case consider passing AJAX responses using JSON. The function `json_encode()` will create a JSON string that uses JavaScript escape sequences for non-ASCII characters, which avoids any problem of encoding mismatch. Also this is easier to extend to add functionality than returning raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would try, in your php script, to encode everything as html entities.

This can be easily tested by doing something like this before returning the results to javascript:

```
$results = htmlentities($htmlstring);
```

There's also the `htmlspecialchars` function you might try.

More about this here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: `htmlentities` is often problematic. It only entity-reference-replaces the characters that actually have defined HTML entities, so eg `é`->`&eacute;`, but `e̋`->`e̋`, so it doesn't solve the whole problem of non-ASCII characters. Also the default `encoding` argument when omitted (as here) is ISO-8859-1, which is almost never the encoding you're actually working with, resulting in incorrect entity references in the output.